# Assign a Series to several Rows of a Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas DataFrame prepared with an Index and columns, all values are NaN.
Now I computed a result, which can be used for more than one row of a DataFrame, and I would like to assign them all at once. This can be done by a loop, but I am pretty sure that this assignment can be done at once.

Here is a scenario:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(index=['A', 'B', 'C'], columns=['C1', 'C2'])  # original df
s = pd.Series({'C1': 1, 'C2': 'ham'})  # a computed result
index = pd.Index(['A', 'C'])  # result is valid for rows 'A' and 'C'
```

The naive approach is

```
df.loc[index, :] = s
```

But this does not change the DataFrame at all. It remains as

```
    C1   C2
A  NaN  NaN
B  NaN  NaN
C  NaN  NaN
```

How can this assignment be done?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It seems we can use the underlying array data to assign -

```
df.loc[index, :] = s.values
```

Now, this assumes that the order of index in `s` is same as in the columns of `df`. If that's not the case, as [`suggested by @Nras`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44806006/assign-a-series-to-several-rows-of-a-pandas-dataframe/44806099#comment76592260_44806099), we could use `s[df.columns].values` for right side assignment.

Comment: This seems to work for this case, indeed. But then I feel to need to make sure that column order is the same for both the Series and the DataFrame, right? i.e. ``df.loc[index, :] = s[df.columns].values``