# Assign a series to ALL columns of the dataFrame (columnwise)?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe, and series of the same vertical size as df, I want to assign
that series to ALL columns of the DataFrame.
What is the natural why to do it ?

For example

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2 ], [3, 4], [5 , 6]] ) 
ser = pd.Series([1, 2, 3 ])
```

I want all columns of "df" to be equal to "ser".

**PS  Related:**

- One way to solve it via answer:
  [How to assign dataframe[ boolean Mask] = Series - make it row-wise ? I.e. where Mask = true take values from the same row of the Series](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46766416/how-to-assign-dataframe-boolean-mask-series-make-it-row-wise-i-e-where/46766472?noredirect=1#comment80478418_46766472) (creating all true mask), but I guess there should be some more
  simple way.
- If I need NOT all, but SOME columns - the answer is given here: 
  [Assign a Series to several Rows of a Pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44806006/assign-a-series-to-several-rows-of-a-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: Use `pd.DataFrame({c:ser for c in df})`?

Comment: @Zero Thank you ! That works !  What I am hoped is  that there can be special instruction for that purposes - like "repmat" in MatLab. Do not you know something like that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`to_frame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.to_frame.html) with [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html):

```
a = ser.to_frame().reindex(columns=df.columns, method='ffill')
print (a)
   0  1
0  1  1
1  2  2
2  3  3
```

But it seems easier is solution from [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46774161/assign-a-series-to-all-columns-of-the-dataframe-columnwise/46774324#comment80494066_46774161), there was added `columns` parameter if need same order columns as original with real data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({c:ser for c in df.columns}, columns=df.columns)
```

Comment: Thank you very much again ! But may I ask you, is not there any special instruction in Python especially build for such purposes ? Like "repmat" in Matlab .

Comment: I think not, unfortunately :(

Comment: @AlexanderChervov - dinner, so answering now ;)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a different way to look at it:

```
df = pd.concat([ser] * df.shape[1], axis=1)
```